# Find the width of a 2D array with a zero length

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Imagine an array defined as follows:

```
int n = 10;
int[][] arr = new int[0][n];
```

Let's say this array is passed into several methods without preserving n. Can we obtain n from this array?

arr[0].length certainly won't work.

Comment: Were you intending to do something with this or is it just personal curiosity? If you change it to `new int[1][n];` then you can obtain n using `arr[0].length`. This is only if you use 1 or specify a cell that you know will be "n" length though. As others have pointed out, "n" can vary between different cells. Creating 0 "rows" of n doesn't really do anything.

Comment: would you mind accepting an answer if it actually helped you?

Answer (score 3):

> Can we obtain n from this array?

No.

The way I think about it is this. The line

```
int[][] arr = new int[a][b];
```

is essentially the same as

```
int[][] arr = new int[a][];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    arr[i] = new int[b];
```

If `a == 0`, the `for` loop does nothing, so the value of `b` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

since every second level in this array is distinct, you will not be able to find out.

consider this:

```
    int[][] a = new int[10][20];
    a[0] = new int[5];
    a[1] = new int[8];
    for(int[] x : a) {
        System.err.println(x.length);
    }
```

and you will see that each X component is actually a pointer to another int[] object that can be set and mondified independently. by doing

```
   int[][] a = new int[0][n];
```

you never actually create any of those pointers, and you don't create any of the Y components in there.